# Swift compare three different arrays for the correct values same like search index

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Hi guys I am new to swift programming so bear with me. I got some little question need your guys help, I want to ask how do I compare three different arrays values and only return the nearest similar values? Something like this btm here:

```
var str1 = ["hi","yoyo","damn"]
var str2 = ["yoyo","wow","daui"]
var str3 = ["damn","right","yoyo"]
```

When I search for these three indexes example like "hi" and "yoyo" it will return the first str1 results, regardlessly that str2 and str3 has similar value of "yoyo" with str1.

Comment: Do you just want the values that these 3 arrays share?

Comment: No i want to return the nearest most similar value of the array, example when i search "hi" and "yoyo" it will return me str1 values not str2 and str3 cause when i use the for loop method it return me all the values of the array share, i dont want that. I hope you get what I mean....

Comment: So do you want a solution where the thing you search are put into an array as well? Like in your example `["hi", "yoyo"]`. In other words, do you want a function with signature `search(for: Set<String>, in: [Set<String>]) -> Set<String>`?

Comment: Ya I want something like a search function? Can you give me an example of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by getting the max value of items in the intersections of the search area sets and the set that you are searching for.

```
func search(`for` searchItems: Set<String>, `in` searchArea: [Set<String>]) -> Set<String>? {
    return searchArea.max(by: { (a, b) -> Bool in
        return searchItems.intersection(a).count < searchItems.intersection(b).count
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
var str1: Set<String> = ["hi","yoyo","damn"]
var str2: Set<String> = ["yoyo","wow","daui"]
var str3: Set<String> = ["damn","right","yoyo"]

let area = [str1, str2, str3]

search(for: ["yoyo", "hi"], in: area)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper I want to ask how do I print out the search results? Like it only print(str1) for the success result?

Comment: @user3711175 Can't you just do `print(search(for: ["yoyo", "hi"], in: area))`?

Comment: Thanks vry much sweeper

Comment: Hi sweeper one more question I got this error 'Swift.Array<Swift.String>' (0x103808028) to 'Swift.Set<Swift.String>' (0x108478028). Is it i need to change my string result to set array, or is there a way of using nsstring. Cause I am using nstring not set

Comment: You can convert an array to a set just by doing `Set<String>(yourArray)` @user3711175

Comment: let str1Arr1 = str1.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
Hi Sweeper How do i convert this to set<string> array, it is giving me unable to convert [string] to set <string>

Comment: @user3711175 `Set<String>(str1Arr1)` should work. But isn't `str1` your array `["hi","yoyo","damn"]`?

Comment: No i use speech to text and then convert the text into a list of array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141858/discussion-between-sweeper-and-user3711175).